# slice dosent work in function js

Tags: javascript

Simple thing doing eloquentJS exercise. Slice doesn't return right output from array in functions parameter

```
console.log(swapArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]));

function swapArray(insertTab) {
    console.log([0, 1, 2, 3, 4].slice(2, 4)); // this work fine
    insertTab.slice(2, 4); // this does nothing
    return insertTab;
}
```

Comment: `insertTab = insertTab.slice(2, 4);`

Comment: Thanks man! So obious. feel so stupid now -_-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) doesn't mutate the array it is called on, but returns a new array. Assign this return value to `insertTab` and it works fine:

```js
console.log(swapArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]));

function swapArray(insertTab) {
  console.log([0, 1, 2, 3, 4].slice(2, 4));
  insertTab = insertTab.slice(2, 4);
  return insertTab;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log(swapArray([1,2,3,4,5,6,7]));    
 function swapArray(insertTab){  
     console.log([0, 1, 2, 3, 4].slice(2, 4));   
     insertTab = insertTab.slice(2, 4);
     return insertTab;  
}
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/dy5L54jt/)**

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) it states

> The `slice()` method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object selected from begin to end (*end not included*). **The original array will not be modified**.

So, in your case, just return the part you want directly

```
function swapArray(insertTab) {
    console.log([0, 1, 2, 3, 4].slice(2, 4)); // this work fine
    return insertTab.slice(2, 4);
}
```